# libmorph API documentation

Tags: c++, c, image-processing

I'm looking for an image morphing library in c/c++ .
In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459793/does-anybody-know-good-graphical-morphing-code-or-algorithm/460113#460113) there was a suggestion for libmorph .
The problem is there is no documentation for it , even on ubuntu there is no libmorph-doc .
does anybody know where i can find its documentation ?
I also found on github "libmorph" by [yacp](https://github.com/fd00/yacp/tree/master/libmorph) but i don't think its the same .

If there isn't , can you please suggest to me another library that have ?

Comment: What makes you think that Ubuntu should have packaged documentations to everything? And according to their site, libmorph is dead since 2004.

Comment: You might like to check the sources.

Answer (score 2):

The libmorph Debian package has this Copyright file:

http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/x/xmorph/xmorph_20140707+nmu1_copyright

That file says the source code is here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmorph

Which it is. In the libmorph subdirectory of the source tree, there is a README.libmorph:

http://sourceforge.net/p/xmorph/code/HEAD/tree/xmorph-current/libmorph/

Some of the header files in that directory seem to be commented, some don't.  Other links also lead to here, the home page for the project:

http://xmorph.sourceforge.net/

That page talks a bit about libmorph and has links to slides and other resources.

(Source: I Googled "libmorph" and followed the links.)

Comment: wow you can google , im surprised . btw i did find all the above , did any of it explain how to use the LIBMORPH api not xmorph , no , do they have a source code , yes , but what did i ask for ? documnetation . please u being smartass doesn't help . if u dont like the question please dont bother writing unrelated answer.

Comment: I genuinely thought I was being helpful. Sorry if it seemed rude.

Comment: @Epsilon If you want to find documentation, should we write it now for you? We can´t do more than searching, and apparently there is no real documentation. So suck it up and study the code, instead of insulting everyone here.

Comment: @Epsilon With that attitude, no other community or whatever will be ok for you. Just calm down a bit. Regarding insulting, I remember your deleted comment very well. Regarding the question, you got the answer, right? The bits and pieces in the links above is everything available. And while I don´t like some things on SO too, everything is fine *here* in this question except your behavior. (I won´t reply to your comments anymore except they get better)